# Помогите с $_SESSION, почему то не выполняется условие if

Tags: php, сессия

Вот код:

```
      public function townUse($town)
      {
        $town = strtoupper($town);
        if( array_key_exists($town,$_SESSION['towns']) ){
            if($_SESSION['towns'][$town] == 1){
                return false;
            }else{
                $_SESSION['towns'][$town] = 1;
                var_dump($_SESSION['towns']);
                return true;
            }
        }else{
            return false;
        }
     }
```

**$town - любой город**

Когда $town = 1 ( var_dump в помощь ), то все равно функция возвращает true, почему?

P.S. $_SESSION['towns'] я заполнил другой функцией, так что она не пустая

Comment: `var_dump($_SESSION['towns'])` в студию

Answer (score 0):

Проверяйте данные, которые вы передаёте в этот метод. Я его немного изменил, что бы можно было запустить на локалке - он исправно работает:

```
$town = 1;
$_SESSION['towns'] = ['Москва', 'Питер'];

/*public */function townUse($town)
  {
    $town = strtoupper($town);
    if ( array_key_exists($town,$_SESSION['towns']) ) {
        if ($_SESSION['towns'][$town] == 1) {
            return false;
        } else {
            $_SESSION['towns'][$town] = 1;
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
 }

echo '<pre>'; var_dump(townUse($town)); echo '</pre>';
/*
bool(true)
*/
```